# Am I using database connection pooling right?

Tags: mongodb, haskell, heroku, database-connection

I have a small [Scotty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) application that connects to a [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) database using [persistent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent) (the app is hosted on Heroku and uses a MongoLab database). I'm new to the world of this relatively low-level database interaction; previously I've used Yesod where most of the details are abstracted. I wanted to ask whether my method of using database connection pools is appropriate!

The app is set up in the `main` function, which does basically this:

```hs
main = withMongoDBPool ... $ \pool -> scotty 8000 (app pool)
```

There are tons of parameters to `withMongoDBPool` that I've omitted. Then the application code uses the pool in a call to `runMongoDBPool`:

```hs
app pool = do
    get "/:id" $ do
        itemId <- param "id"
        item <- runDB $ selectFirst [ItemIdent ==. itemId] []
        case item of
            Just _  -> text "found it :)"
            Nothing -> text "not found :(" >> status notFound404
    where
        runDB action = liftIO $ runMongoDBPool master action pool
```

In previous code, I would use `withMongoDBPool` inside `runDB`, which worked, but as I understand it, would have created a new connection pool for each call of `runDB`. I just want to verify that this approach is the intended use of database connection pooling, and in particular `persistent-mongoDB`'s interface.

The actual code is [here](https://github.com/knowledge-graph/simple-storage/blob/d7bee5d943989d51cd9010bb880ac8af1fdfc6c4/src/Server.hs).

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Non-scaffolded-MongoDB-App

Comment: @Sibi thanks, I had seen that, but there's still a lot of Yesod magic going on, in particular the implementation of `runDB` - though looking through it again, I have now noticed the `createPoolConfig` function, so thanks! It does look analogous to what I'm doing now.